# else is executing without if execution in for loop

Tags: python-3.x

```
#print all Prime numbers between 1 and 100

for x in range(1, 101):
    for z in range(2, x):
        if x % z == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(x, end=",")
```

Comment: Please elaborate, what's the result you're seeing, how is it different than what you've expected?

Comment: That `else` is for the `for`, not the `if`.

Comment: this is else attached to for statement not else attached to if statement. Python supports this

Answer (score 1):

Different way to write this would be

```
for x in range(1, 101):
    f = 0
    for z in range(2, x):
        if x % z == 0:
            f = 1
            break
    if f == 0:
        print(x, end=",")
```

Here `f` is only checking whether we found a number that divides `x` completely or not. This is exactly the feature provided to us by `else` statement in `for` loop case.

Also the earlier `else` was not attached with `if` it is in the level of `for`.

If you check the manual you will see that this is indeed correct.

```
for x in range(1, 101):
    f = 0
    for z in range(2, x):
        if x % z == 0:
            break
    else:
        # loop didn't find anything. So we are falling back to this.
        print(n, 'is a prime number')
```

From the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html):

> Loop statements may have an `else` clause; it is executed when ***the loop
>   terminates through exhaustion of the iterable (with for)*** or when the
>   condition becomes false (with while), but ***not when the loop is
>   terminated by a break statement***.

Answer (score 0):

A simple indentation mistake is causing this. The code would rather be:

```
for x in range(1, 101):
    for z in range(2, x):
        if x % z == 0:
            break
        else:
            print(x, end=",")
```

As the else statement is for the if block and not the for loop.